# como obtener un link de una tabla raspada con beautifulsoup que coincida con un DF filtrado

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Estoy realizando un raspado a una tabla. Esta tabla tiene varias filas las cuales contienen varias etiquetas  estas etiquetas las obtengo con `rows2 = rows[1].find('a')` dentro de esta etiqueta capturo el primer href de la tabla que se encuentra en el indice 2, esto lo capturo con `rows2[0].get('href')`.

El error que tengo es que al generar un filtro al df de solo las filas que necesito la etiqueta  sigue siendo la del indice1 y no de la fila filtrada indice 3 en el df, como puedo solucionar esto?

**ejemplo tabla antes de filtrar filas:**

```
0| fecha | lugar | info |
1|dato1  |dato2  |dato2 | <- fila donde se obtiene etiqueta <a> y <href>
2|dato2  |dato2  |dato2 |
3|dato3  |dato2  |dato2 |
4|dato4  |dato2  |dato2 |
5|dato5  |dato2  |dato2 |
```

**df filtrado:**

```
    0| fecha | lugar | info |
    3|dato3  |dato2  |dato2 | <- la etiqueta que captura es la del index 1, no del index 3
    4|dato4  |dato2  |dato2 |
```

Comment: Buen día, no es muy claro lo que estás preguntando, ¿Deseas seleccionar la fila con índice 1? ¿Qué filtro estás utilizando en tu df?

Comment: seleccionar la de indice 3 con el df ya filtrado. necesito  hacer que en el dataset  incluya la url de img de cada fila

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Para seleccionar filas de un `dataframe` puedes utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) o [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

Como no incluiste tus datos cree un `dataframe` de ejemplo y tendrás que adaptarlo:

```
    A   B
0   1   10
1   2   20
2   3   30
3   2   40
4   5   50
5   2   60
```

Al filtrar los valores de la columna "A" que sean igual a 2 con `df[df['A'] == 2]` obtenemos un `dataframe parcial` como el siguiente:

```
    A   B
1   2   20
3   2   40
5   2   60
```

Luego seleccionamos la fila con índice 3

```
print(df[df['A'] == 2].loc[3])
```

Esto nos devuelve:

```
A     2
B    40
Name: 3, dtype: int64
```

Si quisieras seleccionar por ejemplo el valor de alguna columna puedes indicarlo a través del `loc` o `iloc`

```
print(df[df['A'] == 2].loc[3,'B'])
```

Esto nos devuelve:

```
40
```

**Nota:** `loc` y `iloc` funcionan un poco diferente, por favor revisa la documentación